# i have a problem with compiling javaee project

Tags: jsp, java-ee-7

here's my jsp code for gender input field:

```
<div class="inputfield">
        <label for="gender" class="inputlabel"> Gender : </label>  
        <select name="gender">
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
        </div>
```

and here's my enum for "gender" values : (com.airline.models)

```
public enum Gender {
    Male,
    Female
}
```

and here's my java code in doPost method: (com.airline.controllers)

```
String gender = request.getParameter("gender"); 
    p.setGender(Gender.valueOf(gender));
// p is a object of a class
```

when i try to run my project it says:

> No enum constant com.airline.models.Gender.male
>       The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.airline.models.Gender.male
>           java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)
>           com.airline.models.Gender.valueOf(Gender.java:1)
>           com.airline.controllers.AddPassenger.doPost(AddPassenger.java:102)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>           javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>           org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: Case error? Try changing `<option value="male">` to `<option value="Male">`

Comment: `No enum constant com.airline.models.Gender.male`

Answer (score 0):

When using `valueOf` the string value must be exactly the same of the name of the enum. Case included. So you should use:

```
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
```

Or, following naming convenions for Enums, change your enum to:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE
}
```

And in your JSP:

```
<option value="MALE">Male</option>
<option value="FEMALE">Female</option>
```